# How do you add a custom attribute to a web control adapter, with intellisense support?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, intellisense, web-controls

I created a CheckBoxList Adapter that inherits from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Adapters.WebControlAdapter. Now, I would like to know how I can add a custom attribute to my adapter and how to have intellisense recognize that new attribute.

My attribute is called DisabledCssClass, and I would like to be able to write something like:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="anID" 
    runat="server"  
    CssClass="checkBoxList"
    DisabledCssClass="SomeCssClass"
    DataSourceID="SomeDatasourceId" 
    DataTextField="SomeTextField" 
    DataValueField="SomeValueField"
    RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
    RepeatLayout="Table"
    RepeatColumns="4">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

In my adapter class, I added:

```
private string disabledCssClass;

public string DisabledCssClass
{
    get
    {
        return (disabledCssClass == null ? String.Empty : disabledCssClass);
    }
    set
    {
        disabledCssClass = value;
    }
}
```

The two things I need to know are:

1. How do I do to get this property automatically initialized with the value specified in the asp control?
2. How do I do to have Intellisense recognize/show that new attribute?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add custom properties to a web control via a WebControlAdapter (refer to "Drawbacks of Control Adapters" http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/How_To_Control_Adapters.aspx).

Your best approach would be to either create your own class inheriting from CheckBoxList (this article is old but probably still applicable https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203142/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100103-1.aspx), create your own UserControl or create your own ServerControl.  I'd go with option 1 or 2.

Comment: You can read custom attributes added to your webcontrol via your webcontroladapter, which effectively becomes the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Decorate each property you want to be visible in markup with [CategoryAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx)  as:

```
[Category("Settings")]
```

---

From my point of view the following will be enough:

```
public string DisabledCssClass { get; set; }
```